# Uncaught TypeError: X.setValue is not a function... but writing out the value (string) works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events, gauge

The line: sseTopicString.setValue(sseValueNumber); is throwing a Type error:
Uncaught TypeError: sseTopicString.setValue is not a function.

If I write out the value (string) of sseTopicString before the . everything works as expected.

What am I not seeing? I tried async / await as well, not expecting much of it.
I just don't see why using the variable would make such a difference. Pls help.

All the conversions to strings and numbers are experimental - none of them made a difference.

```
  let sse = new EventSource("http://localhost:3000/sse-stream");
  // sse.onmessage = console.log


    sse.onmessage = function (event) {
    let jdata = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(jdata);

    let rawSseTopic = jdata.topicname;
    let sseTopic = removeSpecialCharacters(rawSseTopic);
    let sseTopicString = sseTopic.toString()
    console.log(sseTopicString);
    
    let sseValue = jdata.message;
    let sseValueNumber = Number(sseValue);
    console.log(sseValueNumber);
  
    sseTopicString.setValue(sseValueNumber);

// sseTopicString has the assigned string value "Gauge12"
// changing the line to: Gauge12.setValue(sseValueNumber); works (Gauge changes to value)
// sseTopicString.setValue(sseValueNumber); throws the error
// how can I use te variable sseTopicString to achieve the desired effect?

    
     
  };

  function removeSpecialCharacters(string) {
    let cleanString = string.replace(/,|\.|-|_|\|\s|\//g, "");
    return cleanString;
  }
```

Edit: After your feedback (thanks!!) and some thinking, the question was meant to be:

I have an instance of a class "Guage" running at the time of Server Sent Event.

The instance is a gauge/ a pointer. I can adjust/update the pointer by static code:

Gauge12.setValue(sseValueNumber); or from Backend / EJS:
<%= gaugeInstanceVar %>.setValue(<%= gaugeValueVar %>);

At the time my variable sseTopic or sseTopicString, containing the value "Gauge12" comes sent in by the server, the instance Gauge12 is already running.

How can I use the variable to mimic Gauge12.setValue(sseValueNumber);....
because sseTopicString.setValue(sseValueNumber); seems to just modify my variable, instead of modifying the Gauge instance.

Edit 2:

Using eval() would also achieve the desired effect

```
eval(sseTopic).setValue(sseValueNumber);
```

But I believe I should stay away from it and am still looking for the correct way of achieving the equivalent.

Comment: Why [nodejs], [express] and [gauge] tags?

Comment: You did `sseTopicString = sseTopic.toString()` so I would expect that `sseTopicString` is a _string_.  But then you are trying to call `sseTopicString.setValue`.   A _string_ has no such function called `.setValue` Perhaps you meant to say `sseTopic.setValue(sseValueNumber)`?

Comment: @pierpy nodejs is serving, the server sent events via express. The JS library used is SVG Guages. As a noob I just wanted to provide as much information as possible

Comment: @Wyck let's say sseTopic (as well as sseTopicString) contain a value of 'Gauge12'.
When I type out 'Gauge12.setValue(sseValueNumber);' in my code, the Gauge number 12 adjusts to the value in sseValueNumber.

I am trying to make the same happen via the variable sseTopicString, containing 'Gauge12'.

What is the difference, that one works, but the other does not?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other comments, the `String` object has no `setValue()` method. The correct way to assign a new value is to use the `=` operator. So, change the line `sseTopicString.setValue(sseValueNumber)` to:
`sseTopicString = sseValueNumber` without intermediate conversions, that should be fine.
Maybe you are confusing the method `setValue()` which comes from a library, or other objects.
Docs for String object are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: Thank you for getting back. I believe Gauge12 is already defined in the used library and Gauge12.setValue(sseValueNumber) is already returning the desired results.

I am trying to make this dynamic and call Gauge12 (as well as all other gauges) by placing a variable containing the gauge before .setValue.

I am not trying to change the value of sseTopicString

Comment: Ok, "I believe", but evidently it's not! The error says that....

Comment: I am not denying the error of my ways :) I am obviously implementing my idea the wrong way,

I've found something like an instance of the gauges in the library with the setValue function / method, but I can only fit in a small snippet: instance = {
          
          setValue: function(val) {
            value = normalize(val, min, limit);
            if(gaugeColor) {
              setGaugeColor(value, 0)
            }
            updateGauge(value);
          },